# Better way of passing http string var from vanilla JS to Angular2 service

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a better way of passing a HTTP string variable from vanilla JavaScript to Angular2 Service. At the moment, I'm passing it via `window.__myVar` but is there another way without using `window` property?

I tried using `@HostListener()` but I don't think it works if used inside a `SharedService` in Angular2 but works if used in a component.

```
@HostListener('window:js-value', ['$event.detail'])
 onJsValue(val) {
    console.log('HostListener: ', val);
    alert(val);
  }
```

In my vanilla JS I have this: -- I want to pass `passTheResultToAngular` variable  to Angular2 to be used in my http request in the SharedService

This is what I have in my config.js

```
let passTheResultToAngular= 'http://passmetoangularserve.net/api/;
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('js-value', { bubbles: true, detail: passTheResultToAngular}));
```

Is there another way of passing variable from JS to Ng2 Service?

What if the variable is coming from `success ajax call`?

```
success: function (data) {
        console.log('SMm', nodeApiUrl + data.Results.Value);
        var passTheResultToAngular= data.Results.Value;
    }
```

in my typings.d.ts: --

```
declare var passTheResultToAngular: any;
```

Comment: it acts as a global config file that calls endpoints. Which will be used outside angular2 as well.

Comment: Mainly so I can change an endpoint(s) url call, without recompiling the whole ng project. As for "outside ng2" I have other 3rd party tool within the angular project which is vanilla JS which isn't build or can't be imported as ng2

Comment: Nope, I already asked the dev team of the tool that I'm using and they said it can't be imported/used within ng2 without rewriting the whole library which is not an option because its a complete application (mxGraph)

Comment: @Claies its mxGraph :)

Comment: Otherwise if its just ng2, how would you suggest of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a superset of javascript so we can use the variable directly.

For eg. In your javascript code we can write var `myVar` as global variable

In typescript along with import statment you can use the code like below

```
declare myVar
```

Comment: What if its coming from an `ajax call`? I get `passTheResultToAngular is not defined` I declared this variable in the `typings.d.ts`

Comment: I have updated the question with the `success`, its fine if its just a standalone variable. But the actual http string that I require is coming from an api endpoint.

Comment: dont use  let data type use var passTheResultToAngular= 'http://passmetoangularserve.net/api/;
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('js-value', { bubbles: true, detail: passTheResultToAngular}));

Comment: Yeah I used var, that was just my typo in my question. I had to set a global `var passTheResultToAngular;` and set it as `passTheResultToAngular =  string` otherwise it will be undefined when used in ng2

Comment: yes. because let is lexical scope it will be used within the block. and var if you defined inside it IT will be consider as local variable which you cannot access outside of the func